# What are the technologies for building real-time servers?

Tags: websocket, server, real-time

I am a backend developer and I would like to know what are the common technologies for building real-time servers. I know I could use a service like Firebase, but I really want to create it. I have some experience using Websockets on Java, but I would like to know more ways to achieve a real-time server. When I say real-time, I mean something like Facebook. I also would like to know how to scale real-time servers.

Thank you all!

Comment: Thanks @ANisus! I do not understand why downvoting.

Comment: Your question is valid; asking for common techs (instead of *best* tech) makes it less a matter of oppinion, and answers are actually not that easy to find. I've been where you are! :)  In addition to my answer, I know that Facebook in parts uses GraphQL, but that solution focuses primarily on making queries and not on real-time updates - their subscription model has some [limitations](https://graphql.org/blog/subscriptions-in-graphql-and-relay/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've asked the same in multiple forums. Common answer to this question is strangely enough still:

- [*WebSocket*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)
- [*Socket.io*](https://socket.io/)
- [*Server-Sent Events (SSE)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

But those are mainly ways of transporting or streaming events to the clients. Something needs to be built on top of it. And there are multiple other things to consider, such as:

### Considerations for real-time API's

*What events to send to the client*
*How to send each client only the events they need*
*How to handle authorization for events*
*Where to keep state on the event subscriptions (for stateless services)*
*How to recover from missed events due to lost connections and service crashes*
*Producing events for search-, or pagination queries*
*How to scale*

### Publish/Subscribe solutions

There are multiple pub/sub solutions out there, such as:

- [Pusher](https://pusher.com/)
- [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/)
- [SocketCluster](https://stackshare.io/socketcluster)
- [etc.](https://stackshare.io/firebase/alternatives)

But because of the limitation of a topic based pub/sub architecture, some of the above questions are still left unanswered and has to be dealt with by yourself. Examples are lost connections, where [Pusher has no fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097246/pusher-doesnt-receive-events-after-reconnect), neither does [SocketCluster](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster-server/issues/3), and [PubNub has a limited queue](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043538-can-i-use-catchup-to-retrieve-older-messages-).

### Resgate - Realtime API Gateway

An alternative to the traditional topic based pub/sub pattern is using a resource-aware *realtime API Gateway*, such as [Resgate](https://github.com/jirenius/resgate).

Instead of the client subscribing to topics, the gateway keeps track on which resources (objects or arrays) that the client has fetched, keeping the client data up to date until it unsubscribes.

As a developer of Resgate, I can really recommend checking it out as it solves all above question, is language agnostic, simple and light-weight, and blazingly fast.

Read more at [NATS blog](https://nats.io/blog/resgate_nats/).

### Scaling

Let's say you want to scale both in the number of concurrent clients *and* the number of events that is produced. You will eventually need to ensure each client only gets the data they are interested in through either traditional topic based publish/subscribe, or through resource subscriptions. All above solutions handles that.

I also assume all the above mentioned solutions scales concurrent clients by allowing you to add more nodes/servers that handles the persistent WebSocket connections.

With Resgate, first level of scaling is done by simply running multiple instances (it is a simple executable), and adding a load balancer that distributes the connection evenly between them:

[image]

**Handling 100M concurrent clients**

Let's say a single Resgate instance handles 10000 persistent WebSocket connections, and you can add 10000 Resgates (distributed to multiple data centers) to a single [NATS Server](https://nats.io/). This would allow a total of 100M connections. Of course, depending on your data, you might have other scaling issues as well, such as network traffic ;) .

A second layer of scaling (and adding redundancy) would be to replicate the whole setup to different data centers, and have the services synchronize their data between the data centers using other tools like Kafka, CockroachDB, etc.

#### Scaling data retrieval

With the traditional publish/subscribe solution that only deals with events, you will also have to handle scaling for the HTTP (REST) requests.

With Resgate, this is not required, as resource data is also fetched over the WebSocket connection. This allows Resgate not only to ensure that resource data and events are synchronized (another issue with separate pub/sub solutions), but also that the data can be *cached*. If multiple clients requests the same data, Resgate will only need to fetch it from the service once, effectively improving scalability.

Comment: @RenanGeraldo Btw, Resgate stands for *REsource Subscription GATEway*, but in Brazil, I was told it means "Rescue". Is that correct? :)

Comment: I already use Websockets. How is the best way to scale an application like this? I could not find much information on the internet. The best tutorial I have found, it explained that it was needed to use Publisher/Subscribers. Is this the best method?

Comment: @RenanGeraldo I added a Scaling section to the answer. Mainly how scaling is done with Resgate, but I guess similar approach is done with the other options. And yes. You need some sort of subscription ;) .  If you have any questions, you can find my e-mail in the referenced blog post.

Comment: Hi ANisus, sorry for the delayed response kkkk. Yes, it means "rescue".

Answer (score -1):

Butterfly Server .NET is a real-time server written in C# allowing you to create real-time apps.  You can see the source at https://github.com/firesharkstudios/butterfly-server-dotnet.